# How to solve ImportError: dlopen( ): symbol not found in flat namespace '__PyModule_Add' when launching Spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I don't know what I did, but now I can't launch my Spyder:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cjchiu99/anaconda3/bin/spyder", line 7, in <module>
    from spyder.app.start import main
  File "/Users/cjchiu99/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 28, in <module>
    import random
  File "/Users/cjchiu99/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/random.py", line 49, in <module>
    from math import log as _log, exp as _exp, pi as _pi, e as _e, ceil as _ceil
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/cjchiu99/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/math.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '__PyModule_Add'
```

I'm am using a Mac and I had tried reinstall spyder but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.